# Solution to the Friedmann Equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

In cosmology I have seen three kinds of energy densities: that of matter, radiation, and dark energy. I have seen solutions to the First Friedmann equation when the universe contains either one of these + curvature. Energy densities have an equational form: $\rho = \rho_0 a^{-3(1 + \omega)}$, where matter has $\omega = 0$, radiation has $\omega = 1/3$ and dark energy $\omega = -1$. Suppose there was a new kind of energy density with $-1/5 < \omega < 1$ with $\omega \neq 0$ and consider an universe with only this energy and curvature $\kappa$. The first Friedmann equation is: $\dot{a}^2 = \frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}a^2 - \kappa = \frac{8\pi G\rho_0a^{-3(1+\omega)}}{3} - \kappa = \beta a^{-3(1+\omega)} - \kappa$. From this I got the following integral equation

$\int_0^{a}da\sqrt{\frac{a^{3\omega + 1}}{\beta - a^{3\omega + 1}\kappa}} = \pm\int_{0}^{t}dt$. When $\kappa = 0$, I can solve this equation as $a(t) = (\pm 1.5(\omega + 1)t)^{1/(3\omega + 3)}$ and so I have an expanding universe. However when the universe is curved, I am unable to determine the scale factor as a function of time. Can anyone tell me how I might try to solve this problem I created? Will such a universe expand or collapse? Is there an easier way I can approximate $a(t)$ if this cannot be solved exactly? Please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of preference, I'll call
\begin{align}
\frac{8\pi G\rho_0}{3}=\text{H}_0^2
\end{align}
for short. For the $\kappa=0$ case, and evaluating today it simplifies down to the definition of $\textrm{H}_0$. I'll also call $\kappa=\Omega_c/\textrm{H}_0^2$ for brevity.

You've lost your $a^2$ term,
\begin{align}
\dot{a}^2=\frac{\textrm{H}_0^2}{\rho_0}\rho a^2-\kappa=\textrm{H}_0^2a^{-3(1+w)}\color{red}{a^2}-\kappa=\textrm{H}_0^2\color{red}{a^{-(1+3w)}}-\kappa.
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\dot{a}^2=\textrm{H}_0^2(a^{-(1+3w)}-\Omega_c)\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{-(1+3w)}-\Omega_c}}\frac{\mathrm da}{\mathrm dt}=\textrm{H}_0.
\end{align}
As for integrating, I'm afraid you've now been introduced to the Gauss hypergeometric function.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2Fsqrt%28a%5E%28b%29-c%29+da